# Rocket drag and lift based on flight direction - in which frame of reference?

Tags: rockets, atmospheric-drag, guidance, lift, flight-control

Drag is aerodynamic force component *parallel* to the direction of motion.

Lift is aerodynamic force component *perpendicular* to the direction of motion.

> Direction of motion *with respect to what?*

1) **The instantaneous local atmosphere (the air)?** If the wind suddenly changes, does the *displacement angle* (below) change because the rocket keeps going in one direction, but the aerodynamic force changes because the air is now moving differently?

2) **Earth-centered, Earth-rotating frame?**

3) **Earth-centered, inertial frame?**

I'd like to write a few lines of code, but I was stopped cold when I realized that a (very strong) gust of wind can induce lift - depending on how the vectors are defined.

Image from https://spaceflightsystems.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktstab.html

[image: NASA Rocket Forces]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I believe you suspected, it is based off of the local wind direction. Changing winds will affect the way that lift affects the rocket. As specified at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics))

> Drag ... is a force acting opposite to the relative motion of any object moving with respect to a surrounding fluid.

Comment: Afterward, it seems obvious - a no-brainer. But only after someone who knows what they are talking about confirms it. Retroactively-obvious I think it's called. Thank you!

Comment: Where "wind" includes relative motion due to the flight of the vehicle, and not just wind relative to the ground.  Shuttle mostly used the body frame.

Comment: Hence the use of the word "Local"

Comment: As one who dealt with meteorological winds during launch, it was an important distinction for us.

Answer (score 1):

Offered up as a supplement to the accepted answer, since I like pictures.

[image]

[image]

From [Coordinate Systems for the Space Shuttle Program](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19740026178.pdf).

Comment: I like them too! The linked document is a fun read as well. Thanks!