# Angle of attack, or displacement angle?

Tags: rockets, aerodynamics

When I hear "angle of attack" or AoA, I think of an airplane. Usually, both the airfoil and the plane itself have a clearly defined 'top' and 'bottom'. In this case, the concept of angle of attack is applied in cartesian coordinates, and has a well defined sign convention.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_attack) thinks of an airplane also.

[image]

For a nominally cylindrically symmetric rocket, this graphic found at https://spaceflightsystems.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktstab.html uses "displacement angle", which if I understand correctly is applied in spherical coordinates and is therefore generally meant to be positive.

See also [Figure 3.15](https://books.google.com/books?id=dQHMBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA115&ots=pqUy5rK37X&dq=rocket%20displacement%20angle&pg=PA115#v=onepage&q=rocket%20displacement%20angle&f=false) in *Introduction to Rocket Science and Engineering*, Travis S. Taylor

A rocket which is flying horizontally for example could have a displacement angle up, down, left, or right, and it would be pretty much identical aerodynamically. Not so for an airplane.

Are these two terms therefore not really interchangeable?

*note:* my question applies to 'rocket-shaped' rockets only, not car-shaped or [plane-shaped](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17104/12102) rockets or spacecraft.

[image: NASA Rocket Forces]

[image]

Comment: A matter of definition.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm not trying to be cute, or picky or anything like that. I just want to make sure I use the right terms. There is an amazing amount of stuff on the internet, but it doesn't always clearly delineate best practices and usages. So I asked here, where common sense and wisdom prevail. Are there generally agreed-upon definitions of AoA and Displacement angle? Do they differ from each other? The former has a clear distinction between the meaning of positive and negative values, while for the latter, should it always be positive?

Comment: Rockets, even cylindrical ones, have a well defined coordinate system with a top and a bottom; they roll, pitch, and yaw like a plane does. Therefore while in atmosphere they have a well defined AoA with sign. I don't think I've encountered the term "displacement angle" as often; your references suggest that it's an absolute value and combines both pitch/AoA and yaw angles.

Comment: @RussellBorogove OK I see. So if a rocket 'flying straight' suddenly pitches up by 1 degree, that would be an AoA of +1 degree, and if it were down by 1 degree instead, that might be an AoA of -1 degree. And if it 'yaws left' by 1 degree, would that be an AoA of -1 degree?, If it tilted up and left by 0.7 degree in each direction, then would that be +1 or -1 degree AoA? Is AoA really defined for a rocket? Can it really be negative? For a plane, AoA only applies to pitch, not yaw, so it can have a sign convention. But for cylindrical symmetry, you have to treat pitch and yaw together.

Comment: If it yaws left without rolling, I'd say it's AoA is still zero, but it's displacement angle is 1 degree. It still has 'lift' but the lift force is sideways instead of vertical. Pitching 0.7 degree and yawing 0.7 degree is 1 degree displacement angle but 0.7 degrees AoA. Historically, early guidance systems treated ascent as a 2D problem, so they ignored yaw (or dealt with heading independently of ascent) - pitch angle was the primary concern, so AoA was the angle that mattered. All the conventions came from aeronautics.

Comment: The angle perpendicular to angle of attack is referred to as the sideslip angle.  Often alpha and beta.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Aha! I remember seeing those mentioned in a comment yesterday, but I can find it right now. And is *displacement angle* commonly used as it's shown in the figures - roughy speaking $\sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}$?

Comment: I am not familiar with "displacement angle".  It was not a term used on any program I worked on.  But none of those vehicles were "rocket shaped rockets".

Comment: Here's an example of a rocket shaped rocket which uses alpha http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20080048217.pdf  As @RussellBorogove mentioned, this is all about the vehicle's coordinate systems and how they are defined (hence my comment).  Any aerospace vehicles with normally defined x-y-z axes has pitch / yaw / roll angles and most likely alpha-beta angles.  That is just the toolset aerospace engineers are used to working with. Another example http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19750010226.pdf

Comment: The Pythagorean formulation doesn't hold up for large angles because it's in spherical instead of flat space (90 degree pitch then 90 degree yaw = 90 degree yaw then 90 degree roll, e.g.), but it's approximately right for the small angles you usually deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing:

[NASA's introductory material defines "angular displacement"](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/angdva.html) as

> a vector quantity, which means that angular displacement has a size and a direction associated with it.

It goes on to say that the direction is specified by an axis with right-hand rule, so 1 degree of pitch-up would be defined as 1 degree angular displacement around the horizontal axis left-to-right (conventionally this is the +y axis).

For one degree of pitch-down, these three representations would be equivalent:

- -1 degree around +y axis *(minimum magnitude, always positive axis)*
- +1 degree around -y axis *(positive displacement)*
- +359 degree around +y axis *(positive displacement and axis)*

So presumably the *displacement angle* is the magnitude part of an angular displacement value, and whether it can be negative is a matter of convention.

[Angle of attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_attack) is in particular the angle between local airflow and the axis of discussion, generally in a particular plane. For a rocket that will generally be the longitudinal axis (often labeled +x) and the pitch plane.

(For a craft with substantial aerodynamic surfaces the angle of attack is usually given with the chord line of the wing as the reference rather than the longitudinal axis of the craft -- they aren't always the same!)

Rotation around the vertical axis is yaw, and the angle between the longitudinal axis and local airflow in that direction is the *sideslip angle*. Angle of attack and sideslip angle are sometimes abbreviated α and β respectively.